Lagrangian density in General Relativity
Just a silly question, but shall we include $\sqrt{-g}$ inside the Lagrangian density in GR? In other words, is it
$$S = \int{\mathcal{L}d^4x} \Longrightarrow \mathcal{L} = \sqrt{-g}\left(\frac{1}{2\kappa}R + \frac{\Lambda}{\kappa} + \mathcal{L}_m\right)~?\tag{1}$$
Or the following
$$S = \int{\sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}d^4x} \Longrightarrow \mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2\kappa}R + \frac{\Lambda}{\kappa} + \mathcal{L}_m~?\tag{2}$$
Most of the actions I've seen out there (like this one) study classical particles moving in curved spacetime rather than the Einstein-Hilbert Lagrangian density itself.

The logic is as follows:

The Lagrangian density ${\cal L}$ and $\sqrt{|g|}$ are examples of a density $\rho$; it transforms with the inverse Jacobian $J=\det\frac{\partial x^{\prime}}{\partial x}$ under general coordinate transformations $x\to x^{\prime}$.

Conversely, the measure $d^dx$ transforms with the Jacobian $J$ under general coordinate transformations $x\to x^{\prime}$.

The product $\rho d^dx$ and the quotient $\frac{\cal L}{\sqrt{|g|}}$ are examples of a scalar; it is invariant under general coordinate transformations $x\to x^{\prime}$.

In particular the action $S=\int {\cal L} d^dx$ is an integrated scalar and a geometric object; it is invariant under general coordinate transformations $x\to x^{\prime}$.

In contrast the quantity ${\cal L}$ in OP's eq. (2) is a scalar; not a density.



I would also add a comment about the various conventions and definitions, since in field theory we usually write $S = \int \mathscr{L} , \sqrt{|g|} , d^4 x$, where $\mathscr{L}$ is still called a "Lagrangian density" while it's a coordinates invariant scalar quantity (like $\sqrt{|g|} , d^4 x$).

@Cham so both Lagrangian densities are valid? In https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653893/question-on-the-einstein-hilbert-action?rq=1 they seem to reach that conclusion, since both ways you get the same field equations.
If we compare it to other cases, how do they handle it? Don’t they exclude the volume element from the Lagrangian?

Here in page 4 they define it for the ADM formalism including $\sqrt{-g}$ in $\mathcal{L}$ https://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr11.pdf

@Antoniou, there are several notations and conventions possible and each one is valid if it is stated clearly. You may consider $\mathcal{L}$ in $S = \int \mathcal{L} , d^4 x$ and call it the "Lagrangian density".  In this case, it isn't a coordinates scalar. It's a "density" as defined above by Mechanics. But you may also consider the $\mathscr{L}=\mathcal{L}/\sqrt{|g|}$ in $S=\int \mathscr{L},\sqrt{|g|},d^4 x$. In this case, $\mathscr{L}$ is a scalar invariant under changes of coordinates.  We may call it a "Lagrangian density", but it's not the same kind of density as $\mathcal{L}$.
